# SwiftUI not updating view when Firestore object is updated

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I've got a list of items stored with Firestore and an edit page that updates the database when it's closed. The problem is, it doesn't update the list data until I use a picker to switch to a different view then re-open that list view. Obviously it's updating the database but the view isn't being updated when the database is. Here's the related code:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: ListVM
    
    init(userId: String) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(
            wrappedValue: ListVM(userId: userId)
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                Colors.PRIMARY
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                VStack {
                    Picker(
                        "Show Register View",
                        selection: $viewModel.toDoShowing,
                        content: {
                            Text("Habits").tag(false)
                            Text("To-Dos").tag(true)
                        }
                    )
                    .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                    .frame(width: 150)
                    .onAppear(perform: {
                        UISegmentedControl.appearance().selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor(Colors.SECONDARY)
                        UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Colors.TERTIARY)
                        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(Colors.BLACK)], for: .selected)
                        UISegmentedControl.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor(Colors.WHITE)], for: .normal)
                    })

                    if !viewModel.toDoShowing {
                        habitView()
                    } else {
                        Text("that worked")
                    }
                    
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Button {
                            viewModel.showingProfileView = true
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                                .foregroundStyle(Colors.TERTIARY)
                                .font(.system(size: 35))
                                .background(Circle()
                                    .fill(Colors.SECONDARY)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                )
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                            .frame(width: 70)
                        
                        Button {
                            viewModel.showingNewItemView = true
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                .foregroundStyle(Colors.TERTIARY)
                                .font(.system(size: 35))
                                .background(Circle()
                                    .fill(Colors.SECONDARY)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                                )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showingNewItemView, content: {
                NewItemView(showingNewItemView: $viewModel.showingNewItemView, habit: false)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.showingProfileView, content: {
                ProfileView(showingProfileView: $viewModel.showingProfileView)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            })
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func habitView() -> some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.items.sorted{ $0.dueDate < $1.dueDate }) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination: ItemEditView(item: item)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
            ) {
                ListItemView(item: item)
                    .frame(width: 370)
            }
            .tint(Colors.PRIMARY)
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListView(userId: "e9ntOkxDAEMvAkPAd01kWfr3IL83")
}
```

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Item: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    var title: String
    var period: Double
    var dueDate: TimeInterval
    let createdDate: TimeInterval
    
    mutating func setItemInfo(title: String, period: Double) {
        self.title = title
        self.period = period
        self.dueDate = Date.now.timeIntervalSince1970
        self.updateDueDate()
        
        self.save()
    }
    
    mutating func updateDueDate() {
        var dueDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self.dueDate)
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        var pd: Calendar.Component
        var amount: Int
        // Can't complete the task early
        guard canUpdate else {
            return
        }
        
        if period == 0 {
            pd = .day
            amount = 1
        } else if period == 1 {
            pd = .day
            amount = 7
        } else if period == 2 {
            pd = .month
            amount = 1
        } else {
            pd = .year
            amount = 1
        }
        
        dueDate = calendar.date(byAdding: pd, value: amount, to: .now)!
        self.dueDate = dueDate.timeIntervalSince1970
        
        self.save()
    }
    
    func daysBetweenTodayAndDueDate() -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.numberOfDaysBetween(Date.now, and: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: dueDate))
    }
    
    func formatInterval() -> String {
        if period == 0 {
            return "Day"
        } else if period == 1 {
            return "Week"
        } else if period == 2 {
            return "Month"
        } else {
            return "Year"
        }
    }
    
    
    // Saving Stuff
    
    public func save()  {
        guard canSave else {
            print("Cant save")
            return
        }
        // Get Current User Id
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            print("Problem with uid")
            return
        }
                
        // Create Model
        let newItem = Item(id: id, title: title, period: period, dueDate: dueDate, createdDate: createdDate)
        
        // Save Model
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("items")
            .document(id)
            .setData(newItem.asDictionary())
    }
    
    public func delete() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else{
            return
        }
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("items")
            .document(id)
            .delete()
    }
    
    var canSave: Bool {
        guard !title.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            print("there")
            return false
        }
        
        // Fix This
        guard self.dueDate >= Date().addingTimeInterval(-86400).timeIntervalSince1970 else {
            print("here")
            return false
        }
        
        
        return true
    }
    
    var canUpdate: Bool {
        let dueDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self.dueDate)
        
        guard Date() >= dueDate else {
            return false
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

```
//
//  ListVM.swift
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by Garrett Post on 12/23/23.
//

import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore

class ListVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showingNewItemView = false
    @Published var showingProfileView = false
    @Published var items = [Item]()
    @Published var toDoShowing: Bool = false
    
    private var userId: String
    
    init(userId: String) {
        self.userId = userId
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users")
            .document(userId)
            .collection("items").addSnapshotListener{(querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("No documents")
                    return
                }
                
                self.items = documents.map{ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Item in
                    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                    
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                    let period = data["period"] as? Double ?? 0.0
                    let dueDate = data["dueDate"] as? TimeInterval ?? 0.0
                    let createdDate = data["createdDate"] as? TimeInterval ?? 0.0
                    
                    return Item(id: id, title: title, period: period, dueDate: dueDate, createdDate: createdDate)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I've tried using fetchData() onDisappear, tried passing in the viewModel as an environment object and using fetchData when the finish editing button is pressed, tried instantly swapping from and back to the view when the edit page is closed. None of this has worked.

Comment: Published isn't capable of observing changes to ObservableObjects,

Comment: @loremipsum Okay, I'm pretty new to SwiftUI. Is the fix here as simple as changing the property wrapper? And if so, to what?

Comment: No "easy" workaround, search for nested ObservableObjects on SO, people ask this question daily, there are many different approaches. But it is fundamentally incorrect to do this.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are following some pretty old tutorials, I would suggest looking at some newer references there have been a lot of improvements since code like this was introduced.

Comment: Cool, I'll look into it. SwiftUI seems to be updated so often that it's hard to keep up. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm afraid you are showing too many lines of code.

Comment: It's bad practice to do `wrappedValue: ListVM(userId: userId)` because it won't detect when the `userID` changes. You should add a `let userID` and `onChange(userID) {  fetcherl.fetchData(userId)` to fix this.

Comment: Also, `@ViewBuilder func habitView()` is bad practice, make a struct `HabitView: View` and pass it the sorted list items (use a computed property in parent `View`).